# How to get view from Activity in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have used VS 2019 wizard to create a basic Xamarin application.

It created 2 projects. One that contains the MainActivity (the entry point) and other containing the views (some XAML files).

One of those views has a list of elements. This is the actual code of the main screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:NfcDemoApp.Views"
            x:Class="NfcDemoApp.Views.MainPage">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Capturas">
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_feed.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:ItemsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title="Acerca de">
            <NavigationPage.Icon>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS" Value="tab_about.png"/>
                </OnPlatform>
            </NavigationPage.Icon>
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:AboutPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

This is the actual code of the view that contains the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="NfcDemoApp.Views.ItemsPage"
              Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Limpiar" Clicked="Clear_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HasUnevenRows="true"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                FontSize="13" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Now, from certain condition occured in the MainActivity, I need to add an element to that list. How can I do it? I haven't found any information about this.

I think I need to get the reference to the list, but I don't know how to do it.

Only thing I can do is to use this.Application (in the activity) to get the application reference (which is inside the project that contains the XAML files), but what else should I do?

Any hint, please?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: "certain condition occured in the MainActivity" - what condition?  Is there a reason it can only be handled in MainActivity?  How are you populating the ListView in the first place?

Comment: That condition is a NFC tag reading. I think it would not be a good practice to add NFC tag reading logic in the view. What I need to do is simple. Read the NFC tag and the text record that was read to be added to the list.

Comment: @Jason Furthermore, this project is the same project Wizard creates when choosing page tabs navigation. It contains a Datasource. Maybe I need to add the new item to that datasource, however, things could turn more complicated that way, I think.

Comment: the simplest approach would probably be to use MessagingCenter to send a message from MainActivity to your page/viewmodel